# Prep for Painting New Wooden Interior Door

Tags: doors, painting

Five new [interior wooden doors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Masonite-Classics-6-panel-Slab-Interior-Door-Common-30-in-x-80-in-Actual-30-in-x-80-in/1000055915) were hung in older apartment.  Although they came with what I think is a white primer, they need to be painted.  I would like to tap the experience of the community so as to understand best practices

Questions:

1. The door is already hung, is there a compelling reason to take it down to paint?
2. The door is new with primer: does it need any prep before painting?
3. Is there any reason not to use a roller to expedite the process?
4. Are some classes of paints preferable over others?

Any lessons-learned or pitfalls to avoid is appreciated: especially if you have done this a dozen times or more.

Answer (score 1):

Simple masonite doors can be painted in place. You only have to seal tops/bottoms of solid wood doors, to prevent moisture from warping them.

The primer is laughable, but functionable. Plan on two coats of your topcoat paint. Personally, I'll paint them with a coat of flat, then a coat of semigloss, to prevent that built-up look, bit that's personal preference, not the law.

As far as rolling, go right ahead. Not my preference, but I'll do it in a rental without blinking an eye. Not as nice a finish, but again, that's an opinion. I have lots of opinions. If you do roll, do yourself a favor and use a small whiz-roller- the kind that has a fuzzy outside edge, so you can get some paint into the panel profiles. Keep a brush by your side to brush it out when you're done.

All paints will work. If you go satin or semigloss, it won't stain as much from dirty paws.